# c++ ios_base::app not appending to files in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, append

I am currently writing an MFC application for a school project.
In one part of the application, I am attempting to append data to a .txt file which contains logging data. I want to write data to the file for each time the function `OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)` runs.

Code for function:

```
void CMiniprosjekt_v5View::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    CRecordView::OnTimer(nIDEvent);

    double calibrationconstant = 10.0;   
    ofstream outfile;

    m_antall++;
    UpdateData(FALSE);
    m_pSet->AddNew();

    m_V=Spenning();  
    double temp=m_V*calibrationconstant;


    time_t Tidspunkt;
    time(&Tidspunkt);
    CTime ctid(Tidspunkt);

    CString stid=ctid.Format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    m_Tidspunkt=stid;
    UpdateData(FALSE);

    m_pSet->m_spenning=m_V;
    m_pSet->m_session_id=(m_sessionNr += 1);
    m_pSet->m_data_id=m_antall; 
    m_pSet->m_timestamp=ctid;
    m_pSet->m_sensor_id=2;  

    UpdateData(TRUE);
    m_pSet->Update();
    m_pSet->Requery();
    UpdateData(FALSE);

    outfile.open("datalogg.txt", std::ios_base::app);        
    outfile<< stid <<"                                  "<< temp <<endl;  
    outfile.close();
}
```

If I run the code:

```
outfile.open("datalogg.txt", std::ios_base::app);    
outfile<< stid <<"                  "<< temp <<endl;  
outfile.close();
```

In the function `void CMiniprosjekt_v5View::OnInitialUpdate()`
the .txt file is written to, but not while in the `OnTimer` function.

Any help would be appreciated

- Erlend

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. There is lots of code here that has nothing to do with writing to a file, the code you claim *does* work as intended is not shown at all, and there isn't a `main()` to make the example compilable (and the problem reproducable). It's also rather unrelated to MFC... (I would also like to add that you *should* check whether your `open()` actually succeeded -- `if ( outfile )`... -- as I have a feeling it didn't in `OnTimer()`.)

Comment: You are using a relative path name. That's never a good idea. It depends on the current working directory, where the file will eventually show up. The current working directory is a process-wide property, that can be changed by any thread, at any time. A common suspect is the File Open/File Save dialog that changes the current working directory as part of its operation.

Comment: Like this? 
    outfile.open("C:\\CPP\\Miniprosjekt_v5\\Miniprosjekt_v5\\datalogg.txt", 
    ios::app);

Comment: Check always if the stream is valid after `outfile.open(..)`. `if (outfile) {..}`, or/ and `outfile.good()`, `outfile.bad()`.